# Source(s) of extreme Raman scattering of FeOOH under intense laser excitation?

Tags: hydrogen-bond, iron, raman

[RRUFF's Raman spectrum of FeO(OH) as Goethite](https://rruff.info/goethite/display=default/R050142):
[image]

Bears no apparent similarity to the extreme Raman scattering of this sample of purported FeOOH under 785nm laser excitation with 100x objective that appears at 50% of 300mW but not at 25%:

[image]

What are plausible sources of such extreme shifts in FeO(OH)?

Comment: As the 8000 cm$^{-1}$ shift is so big wrt. any vibration,  are you measuring 2nd order spectra.

Comment: And third order but only in the Stokes-spectral lines -- not in the anti-Spokes shifts.